# What is Authenticated Users group in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I was running `Windows 7 Ultimate (version 6.1.7600)` and for some problem I cannot resolve, I had to reinstall it (I cannot rely on `restore points`). Now I've seen something that I didn't notice ever (neither in `XP` nor `7`): standard users (non-admin users) can **delete** file/folder that they didn't create. To investigate this, I opened **properties** dialog box of a drive, choose **security** tab, and saw that there is a user group named `Authenticated Users`, who have the privilege of **modifying and writing** to every drive. From there if I uncheck `modify` checkbox for `Authenticated Users`, then files cannot be deleted from non-admin user account.

Now, from `Computer Management` window, I choose `System Tools > Local Users & Groups > Groups` from the left pane. The middle pane lists all groups but I didn't see `Authenticated Users` group.

I'd like to give only **read, list and execute permissions** to users in `Authenticated User` group. How can I do that? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've noticed that removing this 'group' from the root of a drive causes all sorts of problems. Removing it from folders within a drive seems okay though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Authenticated Users is a pseudo-group (which is why it exists, but is not listed in Users & groups), it includes both Local PC users and Domain users as explained in [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277461.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

"Authenticated Users" is not a real group - it is a special security principal that stands for
any and all sessions that have been authenticated using some account such as a local SAM account, domain account or an account from any trusted domain, basically, any user account existent in your
database.

Comment: As a rule you should **not** mess with this setting. It can kill all access to your drives.

Comment: I routinely remove this group and leave the Users group because my machine is not in a domain - what potential problems am I looking at? Haven't noticed any yet.

Comment: @Diago, I think this warning is a little exaggerated.  For example, I specifically needed to remove this permission on my user directory, to prevent other users from having access.